# Using laravel to display information meant for a particluar user on his dashboard

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

i have an application that has administrator and users account( e.g nurse, doctor) e.t.c. if a nurse books an appointment for a a particular doctor i want it to display a list of all the appointments in the doctor dashboard anytime the doctor logs into his account using laravel. i have no idea of how to go about it and the nurse and the doctor both have their different dashboards.

The appointment database contains the doctor_id, patient_id and appointment_date as below

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{url('Others/Operator/Appointment/book_appointment')}}">

                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('patient_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Select a Patient</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="patient_id"  >
                                    <option value="">Select </option>

                                    @if(isset($patients))
                                        @foreach($patients as $pat)
                                            <option value="{{$pat->id}} @if (request('pat') == $pat->name) selected='selected' @endif ">{{$pat->tag_name}}-{{$pat->name}}  </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                                @if ($errors->has('patient_id'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('patient_id') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('patient_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <br>
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Select a Doctor</label>
                            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead >
                                <tr >
                                    {{--<th>--}}
                                        {{--S/N--}}
                                    {{--</th>--}}
                                    <th>
                                        Picture
                                    </th>

                                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                                        Name
                                    </th>

                                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                                        Specialization
                                    </th>

                                    <th  style="text-align: center;">
                                        Phone Number
                                    </th>

                                    <th  style="text-align: center;">
                                        Status
                                    </th>


                                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                                        Book
                                    </th>
                                    {{--<th style="text-align: center;">--}}
                                    {{--Message--}}
                                    {{--</th>--}}

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php $c=0;?>
                                @foreach($doctors as $dr)
                                    <tr style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                                        {{--<td>{{++$c}}</td>--}}
                                        <td>
                                            <img src='{{url("assets/images/doctors_pic_uploads/".$dr->pic)}}' style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="img-circle">
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px;">{{$dr->name}}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px; ">{{$dr->specialization}}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px;">{{$dr->phone}}</td>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px;" >
                                              {{--{{$dr->user->active_user}}--}}
                                            <span class=" alert-{{(\App\User::find($dr->user_id)->active_user==1?'success':'danger')}} lg ">{{(\App\User::find($dr->user_id)->active_user==1?"Online":"Offline")}}</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 20px;" class="{{ $errors->has('appointment_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                            <input type="radio" name="doctor_id" value="{{$dr->id}}">

                                            {{--<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$dr->id}}" class=" btn-warning  ">Book</a>--}}
                                            {{--<a href="{{url('admin/Doctors/delete/doctor/'.$pat->id.'')}}" class="btn btn-danger xs">Delete</a>--}}
                                        </td>
                                        {{--<td><a href="" class="btn btn-success xs">Message</a></td>--}}
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach


                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('appointment_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-2 control-label">Birth Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="appointment_date" value="{{date('d-m-Y')}}{{Request::old('date') }}" placeholder="Birth Date" >
                                    @if ($errors->has('appointment_date'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('appointment_date') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Book a Doctor</button>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

it works properly but i don't know how to collect the specific's doctors id and put the appointment infirmation on his dashboard so once he logs in he will see it

Answer (score 0):

You can use **where** at model.

Ex:

```
$appointments = Appointment::where('doctor_id', '=', $loginedDoctorID)->get();
```

You will get all appointment which **doctor_id** is given.

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

Comment: what is the `$loginedDoctorID` for?

Comment: Doctor's id (user_id)